# Shiboken cannot be imported

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Because of issues discussed at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328582/1886357), I want to import the shiboken module. When I try `import shiboken`, I just get an ImportError. But my site-packages directory actually has a Shiboken (capital S) folder, and I am able to `import Shiboken` fine. Unfortunately, this doesn't have any of the methods the shiboken module is meant to have (e.g., `isValid`).  Just to verify, when I run `Shiboken.isValid()`, I get:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isValid'`.

Based on a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301735/pysides-shiboken-python-module-not-found), perhaps I just don't have things installed correctly. But when I enter:

```
pip install --use-wheel -U shiboken
```

I get:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: shiboken in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages
```

So it seems I already have it installed.

**Note:** this may be a special case of this issue:

[PySide's shiboken python module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301735/pysides-shiboken-python-module-not-found)

---

I am using Python 2.7.6, distributed under Anaconda, in Windows 7, with Qt 4.8.5/PySide 1.2.2.

Comment: Look like your have to recompile or remake 'Shiboken' by yourself. Or your can use 'sip' module to  determine if an object has been deleted yet.

Comment: @KitsuneMeyoko sip is for PyQt, not PySide. Shiboken is the PySide equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if you fixed it already; I had the same problem, can you try

```
from Shiboken import shiboken
```

Comment: That works! One of the strangest import problems I've had in Python. Will give +1 to someone who explains why they set it up this way in the first place, there must be a good reason. :)

Comment: Well I don't know the reason, we stumbled upon it accidentally; even `dir()` doesn't list it, although using the `inspect` module will show `shiboken`. The sad thing is that I didn't see it documented **anywhere**.